# How to append values in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, append

```
dictnry={token1:{1:freq1,2:freq1a},
        ,token2:{1:freq2,2:freq2a,3:freq2b}
        ,token3:{3:freq4}}
```

How do i loop through a dictionary with int:dict as key:value pairs and
**append** a new dictionary (*eg:`{5:freq5}` in `token1` and `{1:freq11}` in `token3`*) into its secondary existing dictionary

```
for loop in dictnry:
   condition==true:
      for loop in sec_dictnry:
         p={5:freq5}  #p IS THE NEW DICTIONARY & 5 and freq5 will be substituted with variables
         dictnry[token1].append_for_dictionary_function_or_something(p) #WHAT DO I DO IN THIS LINE

dictnry={token1:{1:freq1,2:freq1a,5:freq5},
        ,token2:{1:freq2,2:freq2a,3:freq2b}
        ,token3:{3:freq4,1:freq11}}
```

Comment: I am not sure what is your question; Lets assume you have `outer_dict={'inner_dict1':{'value1':"x1"}}` if you wanna append new dict you can do: `outer_dict["inner_dict2"] = {...}` if you want to update value in inner dict then you can do `outer_dict["inner_dict1"]["value1"] = "new_value"`; to create new key to inner dict you're doing the same  `outer_dict["inner_dict1"]["value2"] = "new_value"`

Comment: Looks like you have written some pseudocode but haven't tried to implement it. Your question (`how do I do this`) is too broad: it is not clear which part of the pseudocode you are having a problem with. Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another dictionary of the things you want to add:

```
import json

d = {
    "token1": {
        1: "freq1",
        2: "freq1a",
    },
    "token2": {
        1: "freq2",
        2: "freq2a",
        3: "freq2b",
    },
    "token3": {
        3: "freq4",
    }
}

print("Before:")
print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))

key_entry_to_add = {
    "token1": {
        5: "freq5",
    },
    "token3": {
        1: "freq11",
    }
}

for key, entry in key_entry_to_add.items():
    entry_key, entry_val = next(iter(entry.items()))
    d[key][entry_key] = entry_val

print("After:")
print(json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

**Output:**

```
Before:
{
    "token1": {
        "1": "freq1",
        "2": "freq1a"
    },
    "token2": {
        "1": "freq2",
        "2": "freq2a",
        "3": "freq2b"
    },
    "token3": {
        "3": "freq4"
    }
}
After:
{
    "token1": {
        "1": "freq1",
        "2": "freq1a",
        "5": "freq5"
    },
    "token2": {
        "1": "freq2",
        "2": "freq2a",
        "3": "freq2b"
    },
    "token3": {
        "1": "freq11",
        "3": "freq4"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop over you dictionary and once the key is equal to the key you want to append some dict in its value and do it like the following

### Example

```
from pprint import pprint
dictionary = {
                'token1':{1:'freq1',2:'freq1a'},
                'token2':{1:'freq2',2:'freq2a',3:'freq2b'},
                'token3':{3:'freq4'}
            }
for x, y in dictionary.items():
    if x == 'token1':
        y[5] = 'freq5'
    if x == 'token3':
        y[1] = 'freq11'

pprint(dictionary)
```

### Or

```
dictionary['token1'][5] = 'freq5'
dictionary['token3'][1] = 'freq11'
```

### output

```
{'token1': {1: 'freq1', 2: 'freq1a', 5: 'freq5'},
 'token2': {1: 'freq2', 2: 'freq2a', 3: 'freq2b'},
 'token3': {1: 'freq11', 3: 'freq4'}}
```